# skipping columns in table javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day,

I was trying to skip some columns on my table for it not to be stored into my variable but I cant make it to work.

I just want to add a "skip" class on every "th" element  that I want to skip, then that column shouldn't be included on the loop.

but I am stuck on iterating my array that my condition will be false on the next loop causing for it to be stored in my variable on the next loop.

heres the js

```
var i = [];
var value = [];

$('.report-table tr').each(function(){     

 $('th', this).each(function(index){
            if($(this).hasClass('skip'))
            {
            console.log(index);
            i.push(index);
            }
            else
            {
               value.push($(this).text());
            }


        }); 

 $('td', this).each(function(index){
            if(i.length!=0){ //this is where i am stuck right now
                for(var t = i.length-1; t>=0;t--){
                    if(i[t]==index)
                    {
                        console.log("skip :"+index);
                    }
                    else{
                         value.push($(this).text());
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                value.push($(this).text());
            }

        }); 

});
```

and the html

```
  <table class="report-table table" id="dynamic-report">

              <thead>
                  <th width="50%">Period Ending</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="rowValue">Jan 31, 2010</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="rowValue skip">Feb 31, 2011</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="rowValue">Mar 31, 2012</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="rowValue">Apr 31, 2010</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="rowValue skip">May 31, 2011</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="rowValue">Jun 31, 2012</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="rowValue">Jul 31, 2010</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="rowValue">Aug 31, 2011</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="rowValue">Sep 31, 2012</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
             <tr class="indent-0 highLight bold">
                 <td>Asset</td>
                 <td class="emptyRow"></td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
             </tr>
             <tr class="indent-1 bold ">
                 <td >Current Assets</td>
                 <td class="emptyRow"></td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>

             </tr>
             <tr  class="indent-2">
                <td>Bank Accounts</td>
                <td class="emptyRow"></td>
                <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>


             </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making this more complicated than it needs to be.  Use the jQuery [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function to use the index of the current td and match it with the index of the th and see if that th has the skip class.  Click the button below to see this in action.  (The undefineds are just because I was too lazy to check for empty values!)

Just do something like:

```js
$(function() {
 var results = '';
 $('.report-table tr').each(function (row) {
 
  $('td', this).each(function (index) {
          var th;
    $th = $('.report-table tr th:nth-of-type(' + index + ')');
          if ($th.hasClass('skip')) {
            results += 'skipping: ' + row + ' / ' + $th.html() + "\n";
          } else {
            results += 'not skipping: ' + row + ' / ' + $th.html() + "\n";
          }
 
  });
 
 });
 alert (results);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="report-table table" id="dynamic-report">

              <thead>
                  <th width="50%">Period Ending</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="rowValue">Jan 31, 2010</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="rowValue skip">Feb 31, 2011</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="rowValue">Mar 31, 2012</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="rowValue">Apr 31, 2010</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="rowValue skip">May 31, 2011</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="rowValue">Jun 31, 2012</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="rowValue">Jul 31, 2010</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="rowValue">Aug 31, 2011</th>
                  <th width="5%" class="rowValue">Sep 31, 2012</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
             <tr class="indent-0 highLight bold">
                 <td>Asset</td>
                 <td class="emptyRow"></td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
             </tr>
             <tr class="indent-1 bold ">
                 <td >Current Assets</td>
                 <td class="emptyRow"></td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>

             </tr>
             <tr  class="indent-2">
                <td>Bank Accounts</td>
                <td class="emptyRow"></td>
                <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>


             </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow! It worked ! Thank you very much @manishie! :D Ive been thinking about that algo for already 2days now! anyways thank you very much again! your a savior!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv24r511/) that gives a slightly different approach.

Create a variable of the column to skip.

Using two .each loops, loop through the entire table, and use :nth-child to determine the column to skip.

Here's the most important line:

```
if( $(this).is( 'td:nth-child(' + coltoskip + ')' ) )
```

JS

```
var coltoskip = 2;
$('.testtable tr').each( function(){

    $(this).find('td').each( function(index){
    console.log( this );
        if( $(this).is( 'td:nth-child(' + coltoskip + ')' ) )
          {
           $('.putmehere').append( "skip" ); 
           }
        else
          {
           $('.putmehere').append( '-' );
           }
    });
    $('.putmehere').append('<br />');

});
```